# Calculate the word amount from an <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code converts text into equal paragraphs, based on the users input character amount.

Is it possible for the input box to calculate the amount of words for each paragraph instead of being based on the character amount?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/9q1Ls1mz/)

If an updated fiddle could please be provided, would be much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

Thank You!

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    //Lets target the parent element, instead of P. P will inherit it's font size (css)
    var targets = $('#content'),
      property = this.dataset.property;
    targets.css(property, this.value);
    sameheight('#content p');
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
var btn = document.getElementById('go'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1'),
  content = document.getElementById('content');
  chunkSize = 100;
  
btn.addEventListener('click', initialDistribute);
content.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
content.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function initialDistribute() {
  custom = parseInt(document.getElementById("custom").value);
  
  chunkSize = (custom>0)?custom:chunkSize;
  var text = textarea.value;
  while (content.hasChildNodes()) {
    content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
  }
  rearrange(text);
}

function rearrange(text) {
  var chunks = splitText(text, false);
  chunks.forEach(function(str, idx) {
    para = document.createElement('P');
    para.classList.add("Paragraph_CSS");
    para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    para.textContent = str;
    content.appendChild(para);
  });
  sameheight('#content p');
}

function handleKey(e) {
  var para = e.target,
    position,
    key, fragment, overflow, remainingText;
  key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  if (para.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  if (key != 13 && key != 8) {
    redistributeAuto(para);
    return;
  }
  position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  if (key == 13) {
    fragment = para.lastChild;
    overflow = fragment.textContent;
    fragment.parentNode.removeChild(fragment);
    remainingText = overflow + removeSiblings(para, false);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
  if (key == 8 && para.previousElementSibling && position == 0) {
    fragment = para.previousElementSibling;
    remainingText = removeSiblings(fragment, true);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
}

function handlePaste(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  overflow = e.target.textContent + removeSiblings(fragment, true);
  rearrange(remainingText);
}

function redistributeAuto(para) {
  var text = para.textContent,
    fullText;
  if (text.length > chunkSize) {
    fullText = removeSiblings(para, true);
  }
  rearrange(fullText);
}

function removeSiblings(elem, includeCurrent) {
  var text = '',
    next;
  if (includeCurrent && !elem.previousElementSibling) {
    parent = elem.parentNode;
    text = parent.textContent;
    while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
    }
  } else {
    elem = includeCurrent ? elem.previousElementSibling : elem;
    while (next = elem.nextSibling) {
      text += next.textContent;
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function splitText(text, useRegex) {
  var chunks = [],
    i, textSize, boundary = 0;
  if (useRegex) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.{1,' + chunkSize + '}\\b', 'g');
    chunks = text.match(regex) || [];
  } else {
    for (i = 0, textSize = text.length; i < textSize; i = boundary) {
      boundary = i + chunkSize;
      if (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) == ' ') {
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      } else {
        while (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) != ' ') {
          boundary++;
        }
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      }
    }
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

```css
#text_land {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea {
  width: 95%;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}

label select {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h3 {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
}

div {
  margin: 1.2em;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  padding: .5em;
}

p {
  /*Here the sliles for OTHER paragraphs*/
}

#content p {
  font-size: inherit;
  /*So it gets the font size set on the #content div*/
  padding: 1.2em .5em;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h3>Import Text below, then press the button</h3>
  <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5">
  </textarea>
  <input style="width:200px;" id="custom" placeholder="Custom Characters per box">
  
  <br>

  <button style="width:200px;" id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 align="right">Divided Text Will Appear Below:</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It uses jQuery, but as you used the library in your original submission, I hope that won't be an issue:

HTML

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<br/>
<button id='divide'>Divide</button>
<div id="paras"></div>
```

CSS

```
#input {
  resize: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {

  $("#divide").click(function() {

    var text = $("#input").val();
    var wpp = 10 // words per paragraph
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var paras = [];
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i += wpp) {
      paras.push(words.slice(i, i + wpp).join(" "));
    }
    $.each(paras, function(i, para) {
      $("#paras").append("<p>" + para + "</p>");
    });
  });

})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praine/0ydgdap0/11/)

Comment: Would it please be possible for the above code to be linked into the previous fiddle's input, in order to change the input from calculating characters and instead calculate the word limit for each paragraph? Thank you!